# Angular2 Data Service Component not receiving value on Other components

Tags: angular, angular2-services

currently I am using Shared services to pass data from one component into other i set the value on first component and trying to retrieve value on other end, but I am receiving empty array here is my code:

```
**Ist Compnent:**

        @Component({
        templateUrl: './landingPage.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./landingPage.component.css'],
        providers: [LandingService],

    })

    export class LandingPageComponent {
        constructor(private landingService:LandingService) {

        }
     @Input() Location:string;
        @Input() Type:string;

        search(){
            //setting value in landing service
            this.landingService.SearchData[0]=this.Location;
            this.landingService.SearchData[1]=this.Type;
            console.log(this.landingService.SearchData) ///this print the data succesfully but when try to access on
// 2nd compnent receive and empty arrat

            }
```

**2nd Component**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'find.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['find.component.css'],
  providers: [find,LandingService]

})


export class IndexComponent implements  OnInit {
       searchData:Object=[];


     constructor(private landingService: LandingService) {
         }          
         ngOnInit() {
          this.searchData=this.landingService.SearchData; .// getting data of my landing servie  that i have set in first component
          console.log(this.searchData);//getting empty array
         }
```

**LandingService**

```
    import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class LandingService {
    SearchData:any=[];


}
```

Plus i checked using getter and setter but still facing the same issue can any one suggest me what i am doing wrong as I am setting data and console prints the right data that i want to receive on the 2nd component but ends with an empty array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue has to do with your use of the 'providers' option in your component.

**The short version:**

remove the providers option from your two individual component decorators, and instead add it to your NgModule containing these components (or your AppModule).

Update your NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: ...
   declarations: ....
   providers: [LandingService],   /// <- add this
})
export class ......
```

Update your components:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './landingPage.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./landingPage.component.css'],
     ///providers: [LandingService],    // <-- remove this from BOTH components

 })
```

**The long version:**

When you add a service to the providers array of your component, you're basically saying to Angular, i want a new instance of this service for this component (and its children). So, in your example, you're basically telling Angular that you want two different objects of type LandingService, one for each of your components. And since they are two different instances/objects, they will each have their own data.

Check out [the Angular docs for the dependency injection system](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) to learn more

Comment: in Ngmodule where i have place the service component in export or imports?

Comment: in provides..the provides array basically has to be set in ngModule.if you need _singleton_

Comment: in your NgModule, add LandingService to your list of providers for your NgModule. I'll update the answer to show you

Comment: sure, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

You have set `LandingService` as providers in both components. So it is not a singleton service. You should provide it in the `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  //declarations,imports etc
  providers: [LandingService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your providers are not singletons. You are providing the service seperately in each component hence they have seperate instances of that service.

If the components are in the same module. Provide the service inside that modules (`@NgModule`) `providers`. If not make a shared service/module.

Example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module